# Merging one minute ahead time frame values from csv using Pandas Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to compare the test file with model file and then verifying it with the result.
Here is what I have tried till now:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv",encoding = "utf-16", header = 0,sep="\t")
data.head(20)
createmodel = data.drop(labels=['param1','param3','param5','param7','param9','param13','param15','colorsame'], axis=1)
createmodel.drop_duplicates().to_csv("model.csv",index=False,header =True,sep="\t",encoding="utf-16")
createmodel.head(10)
createmodel.drop_duplicates().to_csv("test.csv",index=False,header =True,sep="\t",encoding="utf-16")
createmodel.head(10)
verifyresult = pd.read_csv("verify.csv",encoding = "utf-16", header = 0,sep="\t")
verifyresult.head(20)
result = pd.merge(testmodel,createmodel, on = ["param2","param4","param6","param8","param10","param11","param12","param14","param16"])   
result = result.drop_duplicates()
```

Here are the files [model](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/3b8ec23b356c3806779c26f6ac42f6e4),[test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YdsXB9gmRDu8PMrYunc3gwfJfI4ilKcc/view?usp=sharing), and [verify](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/6cf320e349e507f8be836d82323b931b)

I have achieved the comparison, using the merge statement and got output in the `result` variable.

The only part that is troubling me is that, I need to find one minute later time of the value in the `result.Time` from the `verify.csv` and then merge the values with result in another column. And save it as csv.

The final result must be like the following:
If following is the dataframe in `result` variable:

```
2018.5.1 0:5 0-1    0-1 0-1 0-1 0--1    0   1   -43--42 78-79   Red
```

And verify.csv has:

```
2018.5.1 0:6 Green
```

which is the values associated with the one minute later time frame of the value of `result` variable.

Then the new frame should be:

```
Time    param2  param4  param6  param8  param10 param11 param12 param14 param16 color Actual
2018.5.1 0:5 0-1    0-1 0-1 0-1 0--1    0   1   -43--42 78-79   Red Green
```

which is the final result.

Kindly, suggest me the way to do and achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `'Time'` columns to datetime, which allows you to easily subtract off one minute from the verify.csv DataFrame, and then you can just merge (or map or whatever you want to join them)

```
import pandas as pd

result['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(result['Time'], format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
verifyresult['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(verifyresult['Time'],  format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')

# Only subtract one minute if it is a weekday
mask = verifyresult['Time'].dt.dayofweek < 5
verifyresult.loc[mask, 'Time'] = verifyresult.loc[mask, 'Time'] - pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)

result = result.merge(verifyresult, on='Time')
# or 
#result['Actual'] = result['Time'].map(verifyresult.set_index('Time').Actual)
```

Outputs:

```
                 Time param2 param4 param6 param8 param10  param11  param12  param14 param16 color Actual
0 2018-05-01 00:05:00    0-1    0-1    0-1    0-1    0--1        0        1  -43--42   78-79   Red  Green
```

Comment: I am getting the output. But the result time is in another format. check this `2018-05-03 22:09:00 0-1 -1-0 1-2 0-1 -2--1 0 1 -25--24 2-3 Red Red` I was expecting dots in middle of the date but getting dashes

Comment: I forgot to tell you one thing. As we are substracting minute one from `verify.csv`, we should remember that the date must not be a `Saturday` or `Sunday`. As the dataset I am working on are from the stock market and it is closed on the mentioned 2 days. Please can you make changes?

Comment: @JafferWilson  I would recommend you keep the date in the `datetime` format as above. It gives you easy access to a lot of extra functionality, which it seems like you need. If you keep it in your string format you can't simply subtract off a minute, or determine if something is a weekday. You can always convert back to that string format at the very end if you need to. See my update for how to only subtract for Weekdays